# TOC line spacing using Revtex

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, revtex

I am trying to change the linespacing in my table of contents (using revtex4-1) but with no luck.

My Preamble:

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,amsmath,amssymb,a4paper,nofootinbib,12pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{slashed,braket} % Feynman Slash Notation
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.0}
\tableofcontents
\linespread{1.0}
```

But this does nothing. Any ideas?

I have also tried the package tocloft, however it doesn't seem to work with revtex and messes up the formatting.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please always make a complete document that shows the problem. I added some `\section` and then changed the first `\linespread` command to `{5}` and the toc was very spaced out

Comment: are you trying to increase or decrease the line spacing? and after `\linespread` there should be a `\selectfont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this using the package setspace, and wrapping my TOC in a spacing environment as follows:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{spacing}{1.8}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
```

For line spacing of, for example, 1.8.